# add textbox values to gridview from jquery with out using C#

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have grid view with out any record and i want to add text box values into grid view using jQuery without using c#.

[image]

Comment: what have you tried so far, any sample? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please add your code. Just a snapshot is not good enough. Please refer [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide necessary details

Comment: A. do you mean when you have no records? B. Do you need that the value in that textbox will send to the server?

Comment: i have used below url for reference . but in that code they are using c# code to add first row. i want with out using c#. http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Dynamically-Add-Rows-to-GridView-using-jQuery-on-Button-Click-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: @MoshFeu : A. i want add records dynamically. B. after button click on onClientClick the textbox values should be added into gridview. i want client side coding .

Comment: actually i want to add values in grid view only and i want to edit and delete the records with out using c# and JSON

Answer (score 1):

If the `Id` attribute is static (if not, add `CssClass` attribute to the GridView) then you can just append the textbox using jQuery

```js
function addRecord() {
  var record = $('#newRecord').val();
  addRow(record);
  $('#newRecord').val('');
}

function addRow(value) {
  $('#GridView1 tbody').append('<tr><td>' + value + '</td></tr>');  
}
```

```css
table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Let's say that the gridview rendrer as table-->
<table id="GridView1">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Col 1</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- It's empty because of no records-->
  </tbody>
</table>

<input id="newRecord" type="text" placeholder="Record to add" />
<!-- button with OnClientClick will render as onclick html attribute -->
<button onclick="addRecord()">Add a record</button>
```

Comment: @user3279300 A. You can post each value when you add it to the table. B. You can build a JSON from the table and send it to the server when you want. (Something like [this](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-extract-data-from-a-dynamic-HTML-table-and-store-in-a-database-using-PHP)

Comment: actually i want to add values in grid view only and i want to edit and delete the records with out using c# and JSON